# How to simulate keypress in rust?

Tags: rust

I am learning rust.
I need to simulate keypress,such as pressing "a",and there are two cases:
1、Bouncing immediately after pressing.
2、Keep pressing for 2 seconds.

Any help please.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `enigo` crate and use `key_click()` for the first part and a combination of `key_down()`, `std::thread::sleep()`, and `key_up()` for the second part.

Comment: Link for convenience: https://crates.io/crates/enigo